PlatformException: Cannot retrieve length of file - Occurs on specific device only
I have a Flutter application where users can select and upload images. The functionality works perfectly on my own device and several other devices, but one specific device consistently throws an error.The devices that throwing error is Android.Also the tester who gets the error says that both Camera and Gallery options for selecting images throws the same error.
PathNotFoundException:Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.vat/cache/-1298873552074657863819055220671524260715.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
Image Picker Code:
 static Future<File?> pickSingleFile(BuildContext context, {bool? isImage}) async {
    File? file;
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Resim Seç"),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.camera),
                title: Text("Kamera"),
                onTap: () async {
                  try {
                    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
                    final XFile? photo = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                    if (photo != null) {
                      file = File(photo.path);
                      logger.i("Camera image path: ${photo.path}");
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    logger.e("Camera error: $e");
                  } finally {
                    Navigator.pop(context, file);
                  }
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.image),
                title: Text("Galeri"),
                onTap: () async {
                  try {
                    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                      type: isImage == false ? FileType.any : FileType.image,
                    );
                    if (result != null) {
                      file = File(result.files.single.path!);
                      logger.i("Gallery image path: ${result.files.single.path!}");
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    logger.e("Gallery error: $e");
                  } finally {
                    Navigator.pop(context, file);
                  }
                },
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text("İptal"),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    return file;
  }

After take the image from Gallery or Camera I'm sending it to the server like this:
@override
  Future postMultipartRequest(String url, File? _image) async {
    try {
      final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url))
        ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'image',
          _image!.path,
          filename: p.basename(_image.path),
        ));
      final streamedResponse = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

      responseJson = returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
    }
    return responseJson;
  }

Any idea can help.Thank you.
I've tried package update, tests on multiple devices (1 emulator and 4 real devices.)
